# Is it possible to use multiple AVPlayerLayers at the same time with different AVPlayers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, avfoundation

I am using an `AVPlayerLayer` in a view and want to present a modal view that will play something else while the first one pauses.

It looks like it's not possible to have two `AVPlayerLayers` on screen. I have tried stopping and removing the first one before creating and adding the second one to the layertree. However, the second `AFPlayerLayer` won't show.

Is it possible to have two AVPlayerLayers present each using a different `AVPlayer`?

Comment: Do you have found a solution? i have the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use multiple viewcontroller in one viewcontroller.

then add it to each of them.

i hope this will help u